# Conditional joins MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have this SQL statement

```
SELECT f.form_id
     , f.tba_id
     , f.patient_id
     , f.location_code
     , f.date_created
     , p.lmp
     , p.first_name
     , p.last_name
     , p.phone
     , u.phone 
  FROM forms f 
  JOIN patients p 
    ON f.patient_id = p.id 
  JOIN users u 
    ON f.tba_id = u.id 
 WHERE f.patient_id = 20
```

which returns the following json

```
[
{
    "form_id": "11",
    "tba_id": "10",
    "patient_id": "20",
    "location_code": "",
    "date_created": "2014-08-30 16:46:16",
    "lmp": "",
    "first_name": "Mariam",
    "last_name": "Oti",
    "phone": "2348061356894"
},
{
    "form_id": "12",
    "tba_id": "10",
    "patient_id": "20",
    "location_code": "",
    "date_created": "2014-08-30 17:02:26",
    "lmp": "",
    "first_name": "Mariam",
    "last_name": "Oti",
    "phone": "2348061356894"
}
]
```

I also want to join from another table on f.form_id but there aren't always records on the alert table for every form_id i.e if I execute the statement

```
SELECT status
     , cug_id
     , alert_id 
  FROM alert 
 WHERE form_id = 11
```

and

```
SELECT status
     , cug_id
     , alert_id 
  FROM alert 
 WHERE form_id = 12
```

I may get one record for the first statement and 0 records for the second statement.

My aim is to get a result like this

```
[
{
    "form_id": "11",
    "tba_id": "10",
    "patient_id": "20",
    "location_code": "",
    "date_created": "2014-08-30 16:46:16",
    "lmp": "",
    "first_name": "Mariam",
    "last_name": "Oti",
    "phone": "2348061356894",
    "status": "0",
    "cug_id": "17", 
    "alert_id": "20"
},
{
    "form_id": "12",
    "tba_id": "10",
    "patient_id": "20",
    "location_code": "",
    "date_created": "2014-08-30 17:02:26",
    "lmp": "",
    "first_name": "Mariam",
    "last_name": "Oti",
    "phone": "2348061356894",
    "status": "",
    "cug_id": "", 
    "alert_id": ""
}
]
```

So when I try to do a join I end up getting one record instead

Comment: See LEFT [OUTER] JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join for alert table

```
SELECT f.form_id
     , f.tba_id
     , f.patient_id
     , f.location_code
     , f.date_created
     , p.lmp
     , p.first_name
     , p.last_name
     , p.phone
     , u.phone 
     , a.status
     , a.cug_id
     , a.alert_id 
  FROM forms f 
  JOIN patients p 
    ON f.patient_id = p.id 
  JOIN users u 
    ON f.tba_id = u.id 
  left join alert a
    on a.form_id = f.form_id
 WHERE f.patient_id = 20
```